# Out of Bounds Exception using ArrayList

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Im not sure why I am getting an out of bounds exception, can someone please help, this is really annoying me as I really want to understand what is happening.

public class LoyaltyCardList
{
    private ArrayList  loyaltyCards;

```
/**
 * 
 */
public LoyaltyCardList()
{
    loyaltyCards = new ArrayList <LoyaltyCard> ();
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void addLoyaltyCard(LoyaltyCard newLoyaltyCard)
{
    loyaltyCards.add(newLoyaltyCard);
}

public void getAllLoyaltyCards()
{
    int index = 0;
    while(index <= getNumberOfLoyaltyCards())
    {
        loyaltyCards.get(index).printCustomerDetails();
        index++;
    }
}

public void getLoyaltyCard(int LoyaltyCardEntry)
{
    if(LoyaltyCardEntry < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Negative Entry: " +LoyaltyCardEntry);
    }
    else if(LoyaltyCardEntry < getNumberOfLoyaltyCards())
    {
        loyaltyCards.get(LoyaltyCardEntry).printCustomerDetails();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No Such Entry:" + LoyaltyCardEntry);
    }
}

public int getNumberOfLoyaltyCards()
{
    return loyaltyCards.size();
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't return anything.

Comment: Java code is case sensitive...`LoyaltyCards != loyaltyCards`

Answer (score 2):

You're print out the LoyaltyCards class rather than the `loyaltyCard` instance

```
for ( LoyaltyCard loyaltyCard : LoyaltyCards)
{
    System.out.println(loyaltyCard);
}
```

You should also make sure you have an appropriate toString() override within your LoyaltyCard class or it probably won't convert to the required format

Comment: would this work for the toString(): @Override public String toString()
    {
        return LoyaltyCards;
    }

Comment: It depends what you want the toString to return, it is usually the fields, for example, return "[" + field1 "], ["+ field2 + "]". If you're using eclipse you can go to source-generate toString() override, and probably something similar in other IDEs

Comment: I've just realised, wouldn't i need to get the size of the list to be able to print anything from it, and also Im not too sure how the toString works.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
System.out.println(LoyaltyCards);
```

to

```
System.out.println(loyaltyCard);
```

At the moment you are trying to print the list itself.